# Inequality query on Long key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving some data to `firebase realtime database` for a user every few minutes (5 minutes by default, but configurable). The key of the data is the Unix timestamp. Since the data is too big now for some old users, I am looking for ways to filter/limit the data when I query it from Android.

I mostly need the data for the current day only. I tried to load last 1000 entries and then check their timestamp to see if they match today's date. This works, but it's not optimised and sometimes the data for today is much more than 1000 entries.

So is there any way I can query the data on key and fetch only those objects whose keys lie between the provided value?

**Current query:**

```
Query lastQuery = ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1000);
```

**Example Data Structure:**

```
{
  "1502437050313": {
    "some_data": "some value",
    "timestamp": 1502437050313
  },
  "1502437050500": {
    "some_data": "some value",
    "timestamp": 1502437050500
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the items for "today", the easiest way to get them is to calculate the timestamp for the start of today as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28222953/209103):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Then you can query your database with:

```
Query query = ref.orderByKey().startAt(startTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if instead of fetching 1000 records randomly and then comparing each for the timestamp, you can determine the timestamp for the start of the day and use that in the query to fetch records where the record's timestamp is greater than that value.

I am not well-versed with the Firebase Java SDK, but in JavaScript one should have done -

```
Query lastQuery = ref.orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(new Date().getTime())
```

Comment: Yes, the question is about the same method. I want to know is it possible and if it is, how to form the query?